# How can I find count of rows by each factor level of each column in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, group-by

I have several different datasets with different number of factor variables and an output variable. For each of these data-set I need to find number of rows of observations grouped by each factor level of the variables and further grouped by all variables (columns). I thought a for loop might do the trick but am struggling with it. Could someone please help with this?

the data set looks something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obhxk.png)

and I want the ouput to be 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNxWz.png)

I have tried

```
for (i in 1:length(df)){
df %>% group_by(df[[i]]) %>%  summarise(n = length(i))%>%print()
```

}

but this doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 3):

An option is to `gather` into 'long' format and then do the `count`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, Variable,  Factor_Level, var1:var3) %>%
     count(Variable, Factor_Level)
```

Comment: thanks @akrun. Since I have a few different datasets with varying number of variables and factor levels, I wanted to do this without having to specify variable names for each dataset. Do you think a loop would help for that?

Comment: @AnT `gather` can take index instead of column  names as well. `gather(df1, Variable, Factor_Level, 1:3)`  If they are in the same positions in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like

```
by(data$x, data$y, function)
```

where `data$x` is what you want sorted, `data$y` is what you sort for, and `function` is what you want done to those entries (fx: mean, length, shapiro.test, etc). Then you can coerce this output to a vector using `as.vector()`.

If I for instance have a dataframe with `df <- dataframe(ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), value <- (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70))` then running `as.vector(by(df$value, df$Id, lengh))`  would return a vector `(4, 2, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with a list format you could stop after creating the list. However, this is a (somewhat complex) alternative to the `gather` method proposed by akrun:

```
# Getting a vector of factor variables in dataset
factor_vars <- names(factor_vars)[sapply(mtcars, is.factor)]

# Creating list of frequency tables
freq_tables <- lapply(factor_vars, function(x) group_by_(mtcars, .dots = x) %>% tally())

freq_tables <- lapply(freq_tables, function(x) cbind(colnames(x)[1], x))
do.call(rbind, lapply(freq_tables, setNames, c("Factor", "Level", "Count")))

   Factor Level Count
1      vs     0    18
2      vs     1    14
3      am     0    19
4      am     1    13
5    gear     3    15
6    gear     4    12
7    gear     5     5
8    carb     1     7
9    carb     2    10
10   carb     3     3
11   carb     4    10
12   carb     6     1
13   carb     8     1
```

**Data**:

```
mtcars[8:11] <- lapply(mtcars[8:11], factor)
```